# Issue with Dart WebUI autogenerated code

Tags: dom, dart, dart-webui

I have issue with auto generated code for web components.
Here is piece of HTML:

```
<div id="hidden-ui">
  <div id="auth-form" class="...">
    ...
    <to-button></to-button>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

As you can see, there is custom web component called `to-button`:

```
<element name="to-button" constructor="TOSimpleButton" extends="div">
  ...
</element>
```

On startup I want to move `#auth-form` outside from parent node to document root:

```
Element af = document.query('#auth-form');
Element db = document.query('BODY');
db.children.add(af);
```

It's OK if there is no custom web-components inside movable node, but while `to-button` is inside I get run-time RangeError.

Here is piece of auto generated code:

```
 __e1 = __root.nodes[9].nodes[1].nodes[7];
 __t.component(new TOSimpleButton()..host = __e1);
```

As you can see, there is strict old path to component, thus RangeError exception raise.

How can I handle with this?

Comment: Why do you need to move the auth form at all? Why can't you place it in the proper DOM position in the first place?

Comment: @PixelElephant, the idea is to have hidden DIV containing all UI elements (formally popup forms), which could be useful or not, thus when I need to show authentication form I move it to document root, when I need to hide it – just move it back into hidden div.
I agree, I can use another approach, moreover I've already using another approach, but I think this is reasonable question, isn't it?

Comment: OK, I just didn't see the need in your particular case, but I agree that this could be a problem in other situations.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to display popup forms every now and then. Here's what I do.

I specify this constructor for the dialog/popup:

```dart
var lifecycleCaller;

DialogFooComponent() {
  host = new Element.html('<x-dialog-foo></x-dialog-foo>');

  lifecycleCaller = new ComponentItem(this)
    ..create();

  document.body.children.add(host);
  lifecycleCaller.insert();
}
```

And as you can see, I add it to the document body. However, this only happens when creating a new instance.

Whenever I need to show that popup, I have code like this:

```dart
import '../dialog/foo/foo.dart';

...

// Later at some point I do:
new DialogFooComponent();
```

And what happens is that you have popup forms appearing in the body whenever you wish them to.

When you want to close the dialog, you can just call this inside the dialog component:

```dart
lifecycleCaller.remove();
```

Comment: how can I use html template with this approach?

Comment: What do you mean by that? You don't insert the dialog/popup in the HTML, you call `new DialogFooComponent()` when the user has clicked something, etc.

Comment: I've understood, I've mentioned about HTML-template file, where component described as optionally styled HTML-structure. Like WebUI components does (Dart + HTML).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=12169#makechanges), this will not be fixed in WebUI package, but will in **Polymer**.

> this won't be fixed in web_ui pkg. It should work in polymer pkg.